# Discrepancy between gcc and clang for two phase lookup

Tags: c++

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <variant>

struct A {};
struct B {};

using V = std::variant<A, B>;

struct Foo {
    void alpha(V v) {
        std::visit([this] (auto a) { beta(a); }, v);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void beta(const T&) { }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.alpha(A{});
    f.alpha(B{});
}
```

The code compiles fine with g++7.2, but fails to compile with clang4.0. IF I move

```
    template <typename T>
    void beta(const T&) { }
```

above `alpha` then clang works fine as well.

I think that this has something to do with two phase lookup, but I am not sure. Anyone know what is going on?

Live link: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MnA9on1aI1cYubIi

Comment: What's clang say in error message?

Comment: Sure, but that is an older version of clang and later versions it passes.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: 4.0 is not even a year old though so finding a bug number or something would be useful